# Can center image but can't center div in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-7

I'm centering an element vertically and horizontally. Everything work correctly, except one issue: I can center `img` vertically  in IE7 but I can't center `div`. What style IE applies to image and doesn't apply to div?

HTML

```
<!-- image - works correctly -->
<div class="container">
    <img class="inner" src="http://placekitten.com/200/200?image=2" />
</div>
<br/>
<!-- div - doesn't work (aligned to top) -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner">123</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  height: 300px;

    background: #EEE;
    text-align: center;
    line-height:  300px;
}

.inner { vertical-align: middle; width: 100px;
 height: 100px; background:red; display: inline-block; line-height: 1.3; }​
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kpdxu/7/

Also:

- I don't know size of DIV
- I can use JavaScript, but I can't get size of DIV as it contains dynamic content

Thank you!

Comment: In IE7, `inline-block` is only supported on elements that are naturally inline, therefore, not on DIVs. You can center block elements (like DIVs) with `margin: auto`.

Comment: I might be reading it wrong, but I think they are looking for a way to vertically align the divs.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas thanks, completely forgot about that.

Comment: Maybe one of the techniques here will help http://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/

Comment: @mookamafoob thank you, actually that article helped http://jsfiddle.net/AAQDR/

Answer (score 1):

use this `css`:

```
.container {
   height: 300px;
   background: #EEE;
   text-align: center;
   line-height:  300px;
   position:relative; //<--this will hold the absolute positioned elements
}

.inner { 
   vertical-align: middle; 
   width: auto;
   height: auto; 
   background:red; 
   display: block; // <--display block will do for ie 7
}
```

via jquery:

```
$.fn.center = function () {
   this.css("position","absolute");
   this.css("top", ( $('.container').height() - this.height() ) / 2 + "px");
   this.css("left", ( $('.container').width() - this.width() ) / 2 + "px");
   return this;
}
```

then use it like this

```
$('.inner').each(function(){
   $(this).center();
});
```

but parent has to be `position relative`.

checkout the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kpdxu/14/

Comment: @Jai Unfortunately it's not an option, as size of element is dynamic and can be anything.

Comment: @tMagwell then i think centering with jquery will be better.

Comment: @Jai can't center with jQuery too, as element may contain images inside with not defined size (and I don't want to use scripts that fire when all images loaded).

Comment: @tMagwell **use width and height to auto** and use jquery. i just updated the answer and the fiddle. you can check that if that helps you.